# Angular Flex-Layout is not switching from layout row to column

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I upgraded to Angular 9 and am trying to use FlexLayout. The layout example I am following from angularjs.org is not working. https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/layout/container

My output is in this format which is not right:

```
     [first item in row ][first item in column ]
     [second item in row][second item in column]
```

instead of

```
    [first item in row ][second item in row][first item in column ]
    [                  ][                  ][second item in column]
```

To test this I created a plain vanila angular & material 9 app with a module called Flexer.

Here is my angular template app flexer.component.html file:

```
    <div layout="row">
        <div class="box1" flex>First item in row</div>
        <div class="box2" flex>Second item in row</div>
    </div>
    <div layout="column">
        <div class="box1" flex>First item in column</div>
        <div class="box2" flex>Second item in column</div>
    </div>
```

Here is my vanila angular app flexer.component.ts file:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-flexer',
      templateUrl: './flexer.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./flexer.component.scss']
    })
    export class FlexerComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Here is my flexer flexer.component.scss style file:

```
    :host {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;

        .box1 {
            color: black;
            background-color: skyblue;
        }

        .box2 {
            color: white;
            background-color: rgb(78, 47, 255);
        }

    }
```

Here is my output

[image]

Eventually I wanted my second div container to be shown under the first like this:

```
    [first item in row ...                      ]
    [second item in row...                      ]
    [first item in 1scolumn][second item in 2nd column]
```

Appreciated any help, sorry I dont have a live angular9 demo to display this like plunker or stackblitz they are not yet at version 9.

Comment: You can upgrade stackblitz dependencies to the latest version by clicking the refresh-style icon in the dependencies header

Comment: Also, why are you following an AngularJS guide for Angular 9?

Comment: @Kurt Hamilton - Thank you I am able to upgrade the stackblitz to 9 will add my link soon.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation for Angular's Flex Layout - see https://github.com/angular/flex-layout instead.

Comment: Still looking for a solution. Here is the stackblitz link to the app:
 https://angular-flexer.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

You should add `fx` prefix before each directive `layout` and `flex`.

Your template should be :

```html
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div class="box1" fxFlex>First item in row</div>
  <div class="box2" fxFlex>Second item in row</div>
</div>
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div class="box1" fxFlex>First item in column</div>
  <div class="box2" fxFlex>Second item in column</div>
</div>
```

But also note that you can use `Grid` with `gd` prefixed directives :

```html
<div gdColumns="1fr 1fr 1fr">
  <div class="box1" gdColumn="1" gdRow="1">First item in row</div>
  <div class="box2" gdColumn="2" gdRow="1">Second item in row</div>
  <div class="box1" gdColumn="3" gdRow="1">First item in column</div>
  <div class="box2" gdColumn="3" gdRow="2">Second item in column</div>
</div>
```

In this case, the result will better match your expectation :

```
[first item in row ][second item in row][first item in column ]
[                  ][                  ][second item in column]
```

because with `Grid` you're designing a grid with 3 distinct columns and 2 ditcint rows.
Could be a good alternative depending the result you're expecting.

#### Important note

Don't forget to import `FlexLayoutModule` into `AppModule`.

#### Demo

Here is a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60676509-angular-flex-layout-is-not-switching-from-layout-ro)

Comment: I got the same results as in my post; I have installed @angular/material and @angular/flex-layout; appreciated any help.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a stackblitz demo and a reminder to import FlexLayoutModule.